# how syntax to include parameters by using with or load in laravel?

Tags: laravel

Excuse me, ! have a confused how to include my argument into Model with Controller in Laravel.
This is my code on Model:

```html
class Posts extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    // protected $fillable = ['title','excerpt','content'];
    protected $guarded = ['post_id'];

    // protected $with = ['author','category'];

    public function category(int $limit)
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Categories::class, 'category_id','category_id')->limit($limit);
    }

    public function author(int $limit)
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id','user_id')->limit($limit);
    }
}
```

And this is my code on Controller :

```html
class PostsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $banyak = Posts::count();
        if($banyak<=0){
            return view('blog',[
            "title"=>'All Post',
                'posts'=>[]
            ]);
        }else if($banyak>0){
            return view('blog',[
                "title"=>'All Post',
                'posts'=>Posts::with(['category'=>(10),'author'])->latest()->get()
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

I am confused about how to enter the value 10 in Controller into the $limit parameter in the 'category' and 'author' methods Model

[From there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zivi9.png)

[to there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVB52.png)

Comment: Can you specify what the actual problem is? For me it is not clear from the description and title

Comment: I don't think passing parameters to relation methods is supported by laravel

Comment: you are not the caller of the relation functions when eager loading and things like that so you can't have required parameters to the relationship methods if you want to be able to use eager loading or the aggregate loading ... also the `limit` is pointless since the relationships you defined are `belongsTo` which can only ever return 1 or none

Answer (score 0):

There *is* a way to filter relations:

```
Posts::with(['category' => function ($category_query) use ($some_value) {
   $category_query->where('something', $some_value);
})->latest()->get()
```

However, according to https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads, you are not able to *limit* the relation query:

> The *limit* and *take* query builder methods may not be used when constraining eager loads.